# How to change the order number in drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

I want to change the order number to reflect the year-month-order-id. Is there any way to do that?

I tried the commerce_order_counter module, however the base counter resets to the one from the table every time a new order is placed. I also tried to alter the commerce_order table from myPHPAdmin to change the auto increment value. This changed the order_id but not the order_number. I also tried to change the default value inside the table for order_number but nothing happened. Finally, I tried to create a rule to update the order_number after an order is placed in the cart, still no success. It seems like whatever value I add to this rule is overridden by some other rule.

What else can I try?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: I am on Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_commerce_checkout_complete that is called when the order is placed.

```
/**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_complete().                                                                                                                                                                                             
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {
  // Create a customised order number. We do not need to save the order here, it                                                                                                                                                             
  // is done by the checkout module.                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  $order->order_number = date('Y-m') . '-' . $order->order_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the code inside the commerce_checkout.api.php inside the function hook_commerce_checkout_complete($order). Is this correct? How can I make sure that this function is being called? In which rule?

Comment: Is there a way to change the [site:order-counter]? Because it is the token used to update the order number inside the "Update order number rule".

Comment: The file you've added this to is just for documentation purposes and won't actually be executed by Drupal. You would need to put this into a module file that is custom to your site - I would _not_ advise putting this code into an existing module (i.e. one of the Drupal Commerce module files) as you'll overwrite your custom code when you update.